# Either, as well or too?

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence "Won't you come, either?" right? Why? Is the sentence "Won't you come, as well/too?" right? Which one is correct? Why?
Can you tell me if all the sentences are right? If there is just one correct, which one?

Answer (score 1):

*Won't you come, either?* is different from the other forms.  It implies a question spoken to two (or more) persons. One person has answered, "I will not come." The question asks the second person if his answer is "will not", same as the first person's. It is a bit awkward. A more natural phrase would be *You won't come, either?*; using just the voice inflection to form the question.

*Won't you come, as well?* and *Won't you come, too?* are both correct.  Again, they both imply a question to two or more persons. One person has stated an intention to come. The  speaker is then repeating the question, inviting the second person to come.

Another way to interpret *Won't you come, as well?* and *Won't you come, too?* is as an invitation to one person:  "I am going to Theresa's house for lunch.  *Won't you come, too?*"

*Won't you come, as well?* and *Won't you come, too?* are polite and welcoming in tone.

Comment: They can also imply that the other person is already doing some other activity. _You're sending a birthday gift? Won't you come to the party, too?_

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct if someone has already declined to come.  The latter is correct if someone has already accepted.  I think both "as well" and "too" can be used, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Only the first sentence is correct.

"Won't you come, as well/too?" is grammatically incorrect. As well/too are used to express agreement only when positive verbs are being used.

In negative constructions, the correct form is EITHER.

Correct:
Will you come too/as well? (interrogative sentence, positive verb)
I will come, too/as well. (affirmative sentence, positive verb)

Won't you come, either? (interrogative sentence, negative verb)
I won't come, EITHER. (affirmative sentence, negative verb)

A) -Hey guys, I'm having a party next Saturday! I'd love you to join us.
B) -Oh sorry, I'd love to but I will be out of town that day so I can't come. 
c) -I can't come, EITHER. I have to study for an exam next Monday. Sorry!

Comment: 'Won't you come, either?' is a genuine enquiry. 'Won't you come, too?' is an invitation; the two sentences are distinct.